# Specify optional format extension with an empty route

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My controller looks something like:

```
[FormatFilter]
[Route("api/foo")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult Foo()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to add an optional format extension as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting#response-format-url-mappings). However, I want the route to end up like `/api/foo.json'. The following fails spectacularly, returning 404s for all variations.

```
[HttpPost(".{format?}"]
```

My next thought was doing something like:

```
[HttpPost("foo.{format?}")]
```

Effectively moving that portion of the controller-scoped route to the action. However, that then raises a 500, with the error:

> Error: In the segment 'foo.{format?}', the optional parameter 'format' is preceded by an invalid segment 'foo.'. Only a period (.) can precede an optional parameter.

Apparently, the only thing that *will* work is something along the lines of:

```
[HttpPost("{id}.{format?}"]
```

In other words, it seems the optional format param *must* always follow another param in order to work, which seems like an absolutely bone-headed limitation to me. Am I missing something here? Any ideas of someway to make this work with static routes like this one?

Answer (score 5):

easy peasy ***(*after alot of trial & errors)***

```
[FormatFilter]
[HttpPost("foo"), HttpPost("foo.{format}")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult Foo()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or

```
[FormatFilter]
    [HttpPost, Route("foo"), Route("foo.{format}")]
    public class FooController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("")]
        public IActionResult Foo()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

***tips:**

- the optional parameter 'format' is preceded by an invalid segment
  'foo.'. Only a period (.) can precede an optional parameter
- an action accept more than one route template

Comment: how would this work if you have more than one post routes?

Answer (score 2):

I gave up too soon, apparently, though this has to be one of the most ridiculous solutions I've ever conceived.

```
[HttpPost("~/api/{foo=foo}.{format?}")]
```

Essentially, I'm just creating a dummy param my action doesn't actually take with a default value of the path piece I want there. That satisfies the requirement that the optional format param follow another param, while still letting me statically set my route.

The first portion (`~/api/`) is just a way of specifying the piece of the path without having to change my controller-scoped route. Any other actions still get prefixed with `api/foo/`, in other words.

Whatever works, I guess.

Comment: It seems that {foo=foo} will match anything now, and the route would also accept requests to '/api/bar.json' for example.

Comment: I agree, it's the craziest way to setup a routing attribute with an optional parameter. Do they have a motivation for doing that ?

Comment: @buygrush: Yeah, didn't get that far, but you can add a constraint as well to fix that, which just makes this all the more ridiculous.

Comment: @meorfi: Honestly, not sure. It's probably a side effect of some other condition as opposed to a particular requirement for this purpose. Still, it sucks.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I've setup optional parameters in this way: 
Oh, God, can't format the code well inside that comment box :|.    
`[HttpGet]`
`[Route("{arrivalDate:datetime?}")]`
`[Route("{arrivalDate:datetime}/{departureDate:datetime?}")]`
`[Route("{arrivalDate:datetime}/{departureDate:datetime}/{skip:int?}")]`
`[Route("{arrivalDate:datetime}/{departureDate:datetime}/{skip:int}/{take:int?}")]`
`public IActionResult GetArrivals(DateTime? arrivalDate = null, DateTime? departureDate = null, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
` .  
And it works perfect

Comment: but, that's slightly different than what you need. :|